# is it possible to set the store product details field not required?

Tags: expresso-store

I have a site with a database of products and now I have added expresso store. I would like to make the product info field not be required. I have set the "Is this a required field?" option to no but once I try and edit or add a new product it still asks for a price and a SKU.

The problem is that the client does not want all of their products to be available on the shop. I want to have the custom field be available on all entries but only use those which will fill out the product details field filled out.

Comment: +1 on this one. I tend to use one field group across multiple channels so I don't have to dupe fields that are common. But in this instance I can't do that, so making this field required means I have to dupe others. I'd rather have it as optional and add a note to the field instructions or handle it in my template to only show products that have the required data.

Answer (score 1):

We will consider this, but it would need some major changes to how Store works, since every product would need to be marked as "for sale" or not. Generally the best idea is to put all of your products for sale in one channel, and if you have products which can not be purchased, create a separate channel for them.

I'd be interested to hear more about the use case for this - what sort of products does your site have where some are for sale and some are not?

Comment: Hey there, sorry I totally forgot about answering here, so basically my use case scenario is as follows..

My client's website has a hair care products and hair colors. We list all of the products on the main webpage but for the webshop we decided that they do not want to sell the colors simply because it's the type of product that they only want to let professional stylists use..and also because it's hard to make an accurate color choice based on your screen. So there's an entire category of products that are made only for professional use.